# Puppeteer wait for page and setTimeout not working in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I'm trying to load a page I host on firebase and turn it into a pdf with Puppeteer.
It works fine with just a html page.
Now I get data from firebase and show it in my page, therefore I need to wait for the page to be fully loaded before I can create the pdf.
That works fine when I test it locally with the firebase emulator `npm run serve`.
However it doesn't work in cloud functions, the settimout just keeps waiting until the function is timedout.
The logs show `waitFor` and after a while `Function execution took 120002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`.
I tried so many things I don't know what to do and I'm starting to think it's a bug in cloud functions.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import { VALID_MEMORY_OPTIONS } from 'firebase-functions';
// import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 120,
  memory: VALID_MEMORY_OPTIONS[4],
};

// const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

export const generatePDF = functions
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  // .region('europe-west1')
  .https.onRequest(async (request: any, response: any) => {
    // cors(request, response, async () => {
    console.log(7);

    const hostname = request.hostname;

    let url = '';
    if (hostname === 'localhost') {
      url = 'http://localhost:5000';
    } else {
      url = 'https://myapp.firebaseapp.com';
    }

    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    console.log('launch puppeteer');

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    });
    // debug: {headless: false}

    console.log('new page');

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    console.log('goto');

    await page
      .goto(`${url}/report/A3p71Fl5GD98Sjks5BJg`)
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        return response.send('Timeout1');
      });

    console.log('waitFor');

    // await page.waitFor(10000).catch((error: any) => {
    //   console.log(error);
    //   return response.send('Timeout2');
    // });

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

    // await page.waitForNavigation({
    //   waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    // });

    // Wait for element to render
    // await page.waitForSelector('#end');

    // await page.waitFor(10000);

    console.log('create pdf');

    const pdf = await page.pdf({
      format: 'A4',
    });

    console.log('close browser');

    await browser.close();

    // response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=customfilename.pdf');
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'filename=customfilename.pdf');
    return response.type('application/pdf').send(pdf);
    // });
  });

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request: any, response: any) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    response.send('Hello from Firebase!');
  },
);

// function delay(ms: number) {
//   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
// }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.7.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom"]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but why are you defining the callback function like this: `(request: any, response: any)`?  You shouldn't have to downcast those parameters to type `any`.  TypeScript should pick up their values automatically based on the type bindings provided by firebase-functions.  I've been seeing people do this a lot lately and I can't figure out why.

Comment: because tslint complains about it, it's annoying

Comment: I use tslint unconditionally and I've never seen it complain.  Are you doing something to the config outside of what the Firebase CLI does for you?  I'm super curious.  This should NOT be an issue at all.

Comment: you are right, I removed it and tslint doesn't complain, I use vscode and prettier. I just saw that yellow line once and added :any, don't see it now though, weird.

Comment: OK.  BTW I've never had a problem implementing a wait in Cloud Functions using setTimeout like that.

Comment: me neither, the weird thing is I just tested the helloWorld fuction and the setTimeout is working there

Comment: the annoying part is, everything works fine local, so I don't know what else I can do

Comment: This works without waiting for any timeout; [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58104413/puppeteer-to-listen-for-map-onload-from-within-node/58104582#58104582) (even if its for Google Maps JS API). The page just needs to emit some kind of JS event, which one can bind to.

Comment: I tried without waiting, but I just get a white page, and I tried waiting for an element to load in the dom, waiting for 'networkidle0', use page.waitFor, ... It all works local but not when I deploy

Comment: The most easy might be to attach an empty `div` which one can await, directly with the JS which renders the report, when it is done. There are no JS events available, but one can await the existence of a `div` node... it just needs to be attached in the right moment (when one can change the page, this is no problem).

Comment: @MartinZeitler do you mean add a div with an id #end, and use `await page.waitForSelector('#end');`?

Comment: @Ruben yes, because when making the JS a little more pupeteer-friendly, one can await that DOM node - instead of waiting for a predefined number of milliseconds (which may be too long or too short).

Comment: @MartinZeitler well I tried that, it works locally, but not when I deploy, the function also just timeout

Comment: @Ruben it's unlikely that a web-site does not respond within 2 minutes. The difference in between that script and my example might be asynchronous execution, see `async function run()` and `.then(async browser => {})`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler no the website responds within 1 second, and I use async await as you can see in my code

Comment: @Ruben despite `async` / `await` is based upon promises, `setTimeout` is not an asnyc function and I wonder how far these are compatible. what does `gcloud functions logs read generatePDF` say? You use `await`, but not inside an `async` function. The log should tell where it gets stuck.

Comment: @MartinZeitler it's not really about the setTimeout, that was just a fix I tried that would solve my issue of waiting for the page to be fully loaded before I genereate the pdf. Also I wrapped a promise around my setTimeout and it does work in the helloWorld cloud function. The logs show me 'waitFor', then nothing until the function timeout.

Comment: try to `console.log(setTimeout)` and see what you got. might be it overwrite by any other library. also check if `setInterval` is working for you.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnjum setTimeout doens't log anything, it does log something in the 'helloWorld' function though, weird. setInterval also isn't working.

Comment: if I move it up top, above the line ' console.log('waitFor');', it does log though

Comment: can someone give me some advice on how to debug this?

Comment: or show me a working example of puppeteer that wait's for a page to be loaded, in firebase functions

Comment: ok so I just found out there is something wrong with the url I provide, other url's of slower pages are working

Comment: the url is working when I try it with the local emulator though

Comment: what it have in log if you add it above console.log("waitFor")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import puppeteer outside of your function, so firebase can reuse it. Also you don't need to create timeouts, but you can use `await page.waitFor(5000);` instead. I tried to create a minimal example for your use case. If you still run into errors, please go to your firebase functions console and check the logs, they should tell you what's wrong.

There is also the possibility that you haven't enabled billing on your firebase account - in this case your function cannot reach 3rd party hosts.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

export const generatePDF = functions
    .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 30, memory: "1GB" })
    .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

        const url = 'https://www.yoururl.com/';
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitFor(5000);

        const pdf = await page.pdf({
            format: 'A4',
        });

        await browser.close();

        response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'filename=customfilename.pdf');
        return response.type('application/pdf').send(pdf);
    });
```

Comment: thanks, I have to install puppeteer types for this? It was not available for version 2.0.0 last week, but I'll try an older version

Comment: You don't have to, but it's very convenient! Did it work?

Comment: if I go to the firebase functions console logs, there is nothing, just a timeout

Comment: In this case I highly suspect that the reason for your timeout is the URL you chose. I copy-pasted the exact code above (adjusting the URL to this page right here) and created a cloud function. You can see the result here (takes a couple seconds to load, but then you will get the PDF):
https://us-central1-ankerguru.cloudfunctions.net/generatePDF

Comment: but if I use the same url in the local emulator it does work, also it does work here: https://puppeteersandbox.com/ with no issues, and sometimes even my cloud function works

Comment: I got to a point where it works 50% of the times I invoke the function, this is driving me crazy

Comment: There is something weird happening with your firestore connection... when I open your URL and analyze the network tab, I see this: https://imgur.com/a/SyqvUye
I assume there is some error how you read from firestore... Don't think this should really take >60s. So IMO this is not a puppeteer problem, but rather a problem with your angular app.

Comment: so I found a fix, I create a new project and added a second app with separate hosting in firebase. I think the problem was the service worker. How can I give you the bounty?

Comment: glad you could fix it! no idea how the bounty stuff works, but i guess it already expired anyway^^